# supervisord python import error

Tags: python, daemon, supervisord

I'm trying to daemonize my bash script which starts running python script inside.

Here is my program section of supervisord.conf

```
[program:source]
directory=/home/vagrant/
command=/usr/local/bin/python /home/vagrant/start.py
process_name=%(program_name)s
user=vagrant
autostart=true
```

When I start supervisord it doesn't work. From the log i receive:

```
No module named monitor.tasks
```

When I run the program directly it works. Seems it has working directory issue but I don't know how to solve. Any suggestion?

Comment: what sort of dependencies does your python file have ? what about the requirements ? are they installed inside a virtualenv or vagrant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found where my mistake was. I just had to use -m after python command as follows:

```
command=/usr/local/bin/python -m vagrant/start.py
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, but mine was related with the PYTHONPATH. All I had to do was adding a single line on my program configuration:

```
[program:myProgram]
environment=PYTHONPATH=/home/nectu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
(...)
```

Running on: Lubuntu 18.04 / Python 3.6